# Finding the commit date time of a particular tag

Tags: ruby, github, github-api

I am using github api to get all the details from github. I want to get the commit date time of a particular tag of my repo.

For example: To get the tags of this repo used as example I do:

```
https://api.github.com/repos/fastly/epoch/tags
```

which returns me list of all the tags. Suppose I want to find the commit date time of tag named "0.3.4". 
One way to do this is iterate over each tag in the array of tags and get the commit url of "0.3.4." i.e.

```
https://api.github.com/repos/fastly/epoch/commits/1560ef3cca58b71a9481ede2819d46d3a7a6ce51
```

which has the details of the commit date time.

But is there a way to directly get the details of the commit date time of the tag? I tried the following:

```
https://api.github.com/repos/fastly/epoch/tags?ref=0.3.4
https://api.github.com/repos/fastly/epoch/tags?path=0.3.4
https://api.github.com/repos/fastly/epoch/tags?name=0.3.4
```

All these links, returns me a list of all the tags same as what I get when I do - `https://api.github.com/repos/fastly/epoch/tags?ref=0.3.4`

Answer (score -1):

Instead of displaying the list of tags and searching your tag within it, you rather could use the lower level **[Git Data - References](https://developer.github.com/v3/git/refs/)** api to **directly** access one particular tag, provided you know its exact name.

- **Syntax:** `GET /repos/:owner/:repo/git/refs/:ref`
- **Example:** **https://api.github.com/repos/fastly/epoch/git/refs/tags/0.3.4**

This will return the following Json payload

```
{
  ref: "refs/tags/0.3.4",
  url: "https://api.github.com/repos/fastly/epoch/git/refs/tags/0.3.4",
  object: {
    sha: "1560ef3cca58b71a9481ede2819d46d3a7a6ce51",
    type: "commit",
    url: "https://api.github.com/repos/fastly/epoch/git/commits/1560ef3cca58b71a9481ede2819d46d3a7a6ce51"
  }
}
```

---

***>I was wondering if there is a way to do get the required details in just 1 step.***

As of now, there's no way to directly jump from a tag name to the peeled target. FWIW, besides a commit, although not that common, a tag could point to

- a tag anotation (which may also link to another one):

  - e.g. **https://api.github.com/repos/libgit2/TestGitRepository/git/refs/tags/annotated_tag**
- a git object different than a commit (e.g. a blob)

  - e.g. **https://api.github.com/repos/libgit2/TestGitRepository/git/refs/tags/blob**

Comment: Yup I did that and then from it I get the sha which I use another syntax to get the tag details i.e. the commit date time and committer's name. I was wondering if there is a way to do get the required details in just 1 step. Here we are using 2 steps.

Comment: @tech_human I've updated the answer to take into account your last comment.

Comment: Any way to get the date of the tag using the API?